# CardView column and row weight

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I want to create a `GridLayout` that contains `cardView` I set the height and width of the `cardView` to 0dp and gave them `layout_rowWeight` and `layout_columnWeight` of 1 instead, but it doesn't work unless I give the `cardView` a fixed height and width,
and I want it scroll-able too.
Here is the `XML` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Orthopedics"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Orthopedics"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_rewards_on" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Orthopedics"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_rewards_on" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Orthopedics"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I hope it's helpful to you.